# How to set correct tintColor with selected but not focused UICellAccessory.customView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

In a `UICollectionView` within a `UISplitViewController` layout, I have a `UICollectionView.CellRegistration` that shows under certain conditions a warning badge as `UICellAccessory`.

This warning badge accessory is based on the following code:

```
func warningBadge(cell: UICollectionViewListCell) -> UICellAccessory  {

    return UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: 
    .init(customView: UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")), 
           placement: .trailing(),
 reservedLayoutWidth: .custom(18), 
           tintColor: UIColor(dynamicProvider: { collection in

        if cell.isSelected {
            return .lightText
        }
        else {
            return .systemRed
        }
    })))
}
```

This works fine, except when the focus in the app moves to another part in the Split View control.

In that case the selected cell show a light grey background, instead of a tintColor background (which is correct), but the warning badge still has a selected appearance, which makes it hard to see (lightText on top of light grey background).

In case when the cell is selected but not focused, the image should have the non selected tintColor (`.systemRed` in this example code).

I tried to use `cell.isFocused` instead of, or in addition to `cell.isSelected`, but this doesn't work.

Interestingly, `cell.isFocused` *does* work correctly for `UICellAccessory.label` accessories, but apparently not for a `UICellAccessory.customView` with an image control.

How to give a custom accessory the correct tintColor when the cell is selected, but not focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to make a custom view based on `UILabel` instead of `UIImageView`. Normally you don't need a custom view for a label accessory, but I already have a `UICellAccessory.label` in my cell registration, and you're not allowed to use system accessory twice.

This is the working code I now use:

```
func warningBadge(cell: UICollectionViewListCell) -> UICellAccessory  {
    let label = UILabel()
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")?.withTintColor( UIColor(dynamicProvider: { collection in
        return cell.isFocused ? .lightText : .systemRed
    }))
    label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    return UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: .init(customView: label, placement: .trailing(), reservedLayoutWidth: .custom(18)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the custom accessory retains its appearance even when the cell is selected but not focused. To address this, you can employ the following approach:

Instead of relying solely on `cell.isSelected`, you can also utilize `cell.isFocused` to correctly set the `tintColor` for the image in the custom accessory. However, as you've noted, `cell.isFocused` seems not to work for `UICellAccessory.customView` with an image control.

To tackle this issue, you can wrap your custom `UIImageView` within a `UIView` and then set the `tintColor` for that `UIView`. This will enable you to correctly set the `tintColor` based on the cell's state.

Here's how you can implement it:

```swift
func warningBadge(cell: UICollectionViewListCell) -> UICellAccessory  {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle"))
    imageView.tintColor = cell.isSelected ? .lightText : .systemRed
    
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.addSubview(imageView)
    
    // Set desired constraints for imageView here if necessary
    // For example:
    // imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    // imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    return UICellAccessory.customView(configuration: .init(customView: containerView, reservedLayoutWidth: .custom(18)))
}
```

This should allow you to correctly set the `tintColor` for your image in the custom accessory based on the cell's state, regardless of whether it's focused or not.

Comment: Hi @mrgs, thanks for the lightning fast answer! However, I forgot to mention that the accessory is part of a UICollectionView.CellRegistration. So color changes must be dynamic. I already tried the approach to set the tintColor of the `UIImageView`, and based on your answer I tried to use a container control, but unfortunately without succes.